# Циклический сдвиг массива вправо

Tags: c#, массивы

Как реализовать циклический сдвиг элементов массива вправо в цикле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение в лоб может выглядеть следующим образом

```
if ( a.Length > 1 )
{
    var tmp = a[a.Length - 1];

    for ( var  i = a.Length - 1; i != 0; --i ) a[i] = a[i-1];

    a[0] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот, завалялся (вроде бы эффективный) код на Си. Думаю, легко адаптируете к шарпу.

```
// rotate(): http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/

void
swap (int a[], int f, int t, int l)
{
  int tt;

  for (l+=f; f < l; f++,t++) {
    tt = a[f];
    a[f] = a[t];
    a[t] = tt;
  }
}

void
rotate (int a[], int n, int dist)
{
  if ((dist %= n) == 0)
    return;
  if (dist < 0)
    dist += n;

  int i, j, p;
  i = p = dist;
  j = n - p;
  while (i != j) {
    if (i > j) {
      swap (a, p-i,p,j);
      i -= j;
    } else {
      swap (a, p-i,p+j-i,i);
      j -= i;
    }
  }
  swap (a, p-i,p,i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = source[source.Length-1];    
Array.Copy(source, 0, source, 1, source.Length - 1);
source[0] = temp;
```

Где source - массив.
Согласно тестам, этот способ работает в разы быстрее предложенного цикла. Это можно объяснить тем, что в цикле элементы копируются по одному, а данный метод копирует сразу все, что ему сказали.

Comment: У вас обычный сдвиг, а нужен - циклический

Comment: @PavelMayorov исправлено. Повторюсь, этот способ будет работать намного быстрее цикла, в котором сдвигается каждый элемент в отдельности.

Comment: Вот только ваш код теперь не работает. На входе - [1,2,3,4,5], на выходе - [5,3,4,5,5]!

Comment: Исправил, штоп работало как запрошено.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (diff > 0) {
                //Сдвигаем влево
                var temp = new short[diff];
                Array.Copy(timeArr, temp, diff);
                Array.Copy(timeArr, diff, timeArr, 0, timeArr.Length - diff);
                Array.Copy(temp, 0, timeArr, timeArr.Length - diff, temp.Length);
            } else {
                //Сдвигаем вправо
                diff = -diff;
                var temp = new short[diff];
                Array.Copy(timeArr, timeArr.Length - diff, temp, 0, diff);
                Array.Copy(timeArr, 0, timeArr, diff, timeArr.Length - diff);
                Array.Copy(temp, 0, timeArr, 0, temp.Length);
            }
```

timeArr - массив, который нужно сдвинуть по принципу циклического буфера.
diff - на сколько сдвигаем, вправо или влево.